# How to modify a custom TextView WRAP_CONTENT height without copying and pasting its parent onMeasure implementation?

Tags: android, textview, onmeasure

I am creating a custom `TextView` and I would like to know if it is possible to modify the resulting calculation of a `WRAP_CONTENT` height without copying and pasting its parent `onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int)` implementation.

Let's say that my `WRAP_CONTENT` calculation is equals to parent's resulting calculation + `16dp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  your custom view, let the super do its work then modify the results:

```
override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth,measuredHeight + 16)
}
```

*(Here 16 is 16px, so you would have to do the conversion for 16dp if that's what you want.)*

See [View#setMeasuredDimension](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setMeasuredDimension(int,%20int)).

Comment: That's a pretty nice solution. Thanks a lot for your contribution :). If one applies this solution for the `MeasureSpec.AT_MOST` mode, just beware the limit.

Comment: @AugustoCarmo There is more to a complete solution than I posted here. As you imply, the code would have to respect the contract with the parent for all _MeasureSpec_ modes. What I posted works best for `MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED`. Maximim height would also need to be taken into account for a general solution.